# In emotion, how to define a constrained TS type for css prop so only picked css properties can be interpolated?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

In emotion, how to define a constrained TS type for `css` prop so only picked css properties can be interpolated?

For example, to achieve the following result:

```
// This is considered as valid
css = {{
   color: 'white',
   "&:hover": {
      color: 'black',
   }
}}
// This is not
css = {{
   color: 'white',
   height: 32, // Height should be excluded
   "&:hover": {
      color: 'black',
      border: 2, // Border should be excluded
   }
}}
```

I've tried `Pick<CSSObject, 'color'>`, but this will omit the keys for css selectors.

What I am looking for is any helper type exposed by Emotion. I was imagine something like `HelperTypeByEmotion<'color'|'border'>`

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. What you want to define is a interface that has only color property.

!!! REMEMBER !!!
The typescript annotation does not affect the data itself. You can't magically delete the data that is not in the interface. Typescript types are syntax sugar to detecte errors and type misalignment. After transpiling to js if your css inludes this properties for some reason - THEY WILL BE THERE AND AFFECT YOUR APP.

```
interface WithColor {
  color: string
}

interface MyCss extends WithColor {
  "&:hover": WithColor
}

css: MyCss = {{
  color: 'white',
  "&:hover": {
    color: 'black',
  }
}}

// This should be highlighted as not matching the interface.
cssError: MyCss = {{
  color: 'white',
  height: 32, // Shows error
  "&:hover": {
    color: 'black',
    border: 2, // Shows error
  }
}}
```

This approach allows you to reuse the WithColor interface in other css definitions and reduce the code duplication of your app. The extends will provide the color to MyCss interface and as for hover property you can reuse it again without typying it again.

In order to check for errors in your app use this command.

```
tsc --project tsconfig.json --noEmit
```

As always the official documentation can be very useful. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html

Comment: hey thanks. Yeah I know I can do this. I was thinking if there are any helper Types exposed by emotion I can leverage directly. For example: `HelperTypeByEmotion<'color'|'border'>`...

Comment: I wouldn't do it. I'd stick to the basics. This way when you need to port your code to something else it still works. During my career this approach has proven to be most stable and resiliant way of writing code.

Comment: I think this might be how emotion define its Interpolate and CSSObject Types, so I expect there could be some helper Type I can leverage, instead of re-create the wheel. But yeah I see your point and thanks for your advice. : )